# How to combine two arrays with splice

Tags: arrays, swift

I would like to combine the following arrays but with one to splice itself in part of the other.

Array 1:

```
[Armor, Seal, Attack, Defend, Block]
```

Array 2:

```
[9, 9, 3, 6, 3]
```

I would like the integers to splice themselves each into where the commas are on the first array.

Example:

```
[Armor 9, Seal 9, Attack 3, Defend 6, Block 3]
```

Comment: Not with splice, but with zip.

Comment: What is the type of elements in Array1 and what do you want as a type of elements in the Example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 1.2:

```
let arr1 = ["Armor", "Seal", "Attack", "Defend", "Block"]
let arr2 = [9, 9, 3, 6, 3]
let arr3 = Array(zip(arr1,arr2)).map {"\($0.0) \($0.1)"}
arr3 // ["Armor 9", "Seal 9", "Attack 3", "Defend 6", "Block 3"]
```